# How to set up a mock localhost server in protractor to be a placeholder for another localhost server on a different port?

Tags: node.js, npm, protractor

#### Scenario:

I am trying to test a scenario where I provide the token to my Chromium browser as a cookie. Unfortunately, I cannot add it to the params because I need the method to be compatible with non-localhost GETs.

When I use `browser.driver.get('http://localhost:3000)` the browser tries to redirect to `localhost:3001`.
Since the cookie doesn't exist, yet, it fails to load the page. (I intentionally didn't start the 3001 server.)

I then try to add the cookie with `browser.manage().addCookie({ name: 'siteJwt', value: jwtToken, domain: 'localhost' })`, but I get an `InvalidCookieDomainError: invalid cookie domain` error.

I'd like to set up my protractor tests with a simple hello world server on port 3001, so that the application can properly redirect to that port and I can add the cookie and validate the redirection.

#### Code:

```
describe('Test - ', function() {

    const util = require('./testUtil.js');

    var siteUrl = 'http://localhost:3000';
    var domainName = 'localhost';
    var landingUrl = 'http://localhost:3001';

    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

    var jwtToken = 'boblkja-lsdkfj-lasdkjfhioasjdhfijuahsoifuhaosiuhfoiahfiuhsaoiuhf';

    beforeEach(function() {
        browser.waitForAngular();
    });

    /**
     * Logging in by manually by setting the JWT Token cookie.
     */
    it('T1', function() {
        browser.driver.get(siteUrl).then(function() {
            browser.manage().addCookie({ name: 'siteJwt', value: jwtToken, domain: domainName });
        })
        browser.get(siteUrl);
        ...
    });
});
```

#### Error:

```
  Message:
    Failed: invalid cookie domain
      (Session info: headless chrome=79.0.3945.117)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=79.0.3945.16 (93fcc21110c10dbbd49bbff8f472335360e31d05-refs/branch-heads/3945@{#262}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17763 x86_64)
  Stack:
    InvalidCookieDomainError: invalid cookie domain
      (Session info: headless chrome=79.0.3945.117)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=79.0.3945.16 (93fcc21110c10dbbd49bbff8f472335360e31d05-refs/branch-heads/3945@{#262}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17763 x86_64)
        at Object.checkLegacyResponse (C:\Install\node-v12.13.1-win-x64\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:546:15)
        at parseHttpResponse (C:\Install\node-v12.13.1-win-x64\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:509:13)
        at C:\Install\node-v12.13.1-win-x64\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:441:30
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    From: Task: WebDriver.manage().addCookie(siteJwt=**********;domain=localhost)
        at Driver.schedule (C:\Install\node-v12.13.1-win-x64\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:807:17)
        at Options.addCookie (C:\Install\node-v12.13.1-win-x64\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:1243:25)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this issue, i started a dummy server near the beginning of the protractor test.

To create a server, all you need to do is this:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.write('Hello World!');
  res.end();
}).listen(3001);
```

You can easily change it to html and read the file like this:

```
    const http = require('http');
    const fs = require('fs');

    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'});
      res.write(fs.readFileSync('mock/server/mockLanding.html', 'utf8'));
      res.end();
    }).listen(3001);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the domain to 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. Also try adding a .localhost instead of just localhost. Let me know if this works :)

[Here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/022644c47c643ce6fe797d65e074329190129c1b/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js#L1075) is the documentation for addCookie for more information.

Comment: if you use 127.0.0.1 for the domain, you must use `http://127.0.0.1:3000` instead of `http://localhost:3000` and it still wouldn't work. The site redirects to port 3001 in order to "log in", but since I didn't have that started up (intentionally) it won't work. The idea here is to set up port 3001 with a dummy server so it can redirect to an existing service. Changing the hostname won't do anything to fix that.